# How to find all records that have a duplicate based on a column

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to construct a query in LINQ/Entity Framework that will return all rows that have a duplicate based on one column. However, I don't want to group them, I actually want to get all the rows that have the duplicate.

```
name age
---- ---
john 15
john 16
jack 20
jill 26
sam  10
sam  12
```

How can I get a list of rows that have duplicates based on the name column? This is the resultset I'm expecting:

```
name age
---- ---
john 15
john 16
sam  10
sam  12
```

I tried something like this, but I think this will give me a grouped result I think:

```
var duplicates = Shop.GroupBy(r => r.Name)
                     .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                     .Select(val => val.Key);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SelectMany`:

```
var duplicates = Shop.GroupBy(r => r.Name)
                     .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                     .SelectMany(g=> g);
```

It will help you to flatten the result of each group that have more than one element in just one collection